# Can we show static count without hover in gvisGeoChart | googleVis

Tags: r, google-visualization, googlevis

I am using [googleVis](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/vignettes/googleVis_examples.html) to create a GeoChart and its working as expected. This work on local hosted website but we don't have R infra to host the same website. Now all the count parameter is showing on hover and unfortunately I have to share the same report to my client in Image format where I can't show hover. I am attaching a sample graph where I captured one hover meanwhile I have to show all the counts on each location.

Can someone please help me to show static count on graph, I am not able to find the way to create it.

[image]

Comment: Do you have the data and script to generate the googlevis in the first place?

Comment: use this one, it has default export data  

library(googleVis)
demo(googleVis)
Geo=gvisGeoChart(Exports, locationvar="Country", 
                 colorvar="Profit",
                 options=list(projection="kavrayskiy-vii"))
plot(Geo)